# How to stub (a required) extend function in a jasmine spec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jasmine

I've never really worked with npm, jasmine and node for that matter. So the whole toolchain is a bit overwhelming. I ran into this today:

I want to add [extend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend#usage) functionality to [SIP.js](http://sipjs.com/) for a [PR I'm working on](https://github.com/onsip/SIP.js/pull/143).

If I [`require('extend')`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend#usage) like so:

```
module.exports = function (SIP) {

  var extend = require('extend');

  var UA,
  ...
  UA.prototype.isConnected = function() {
     return this.transport ? this.transport.connected : false;
  };
  ...
  UA.prototype.invite = function(target, options) {
    options = extend(true, {}, options) || {};
```

I assign [the `module.exported` function from the extend package](https://github.com/justmoon/node-extend/blob/master/index.js) to a variable. Now my question is, **how can I stub `extend()` in a jasmine spec?**

```
spyOn(UA, 'isConnected').and.returnValue(true); // works ok, UA has 'isConnected' property
spyOn(WHATOBJECT?, 'extend').and.returnValue(extendedOptions);
```

I also tried assigning extend to UA property like so

```
module.exports = function (SIP) {

  var extend = require('extend');

  var UA,
  ...
  UA.extend = extend;
```

and in the spec:

```
spyOn(UA, 'extend')...
```

But still get an error when I run jasmine.

> Error: extend() method does not exist in file:///Users/wpp/SIP.js/.grunt/grunt-contrib-jasmine/jasmine.js (line 1861) (1)

Is it some global object like window in the browser? Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stub require() / expect calls to the "root" function of a module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997459/how-to-stub-require-expect-calls-to-the-root-function-of-a-module)